# is it ok to pour milk directly into a fleshig sink?

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, appliances

Is it permitted or forbidden to pour milk directly into a *fleshig* (meat-use) sink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a quote from http://www.dinonline.org/2010/05/30/cooking-in-the-garbage-bin regarding using the same garbage bin for both meat and milk, which I think is directly relevant to your question:

> In answering this question, it is
>   important to note that although
>   various authorities quote the concept
>   of a davar gush (solid body) as being
>   able to “cook” (see Magen Avraham 318,
>   Nishmas Adam 20:3), it remains a
>   chumra that is widely disputed (see
>   Rema, Darchei Moshe 105:4, Pleiti
>   (ibid.), Chasam Sofer YD 95, Shut Pnei
>   Yehoshua 2:23, and others). This
>   opening point gives the following
>   considerations significant weight.
>
> 1. Davar She’eino Miskaven: See Iggros Moshe YD 39, Yad Yehudah 92, among
>      others, who write that (like other
>      prohibitions) the prohibition of
>      cooking meat and milk does not apply
>      where it is a davar she’eino miskaven.
>      In our case it is hard to call the
>      single garbage bin a “pesik reishei”
>      for mixing meat and milk — by the time
>      the teabag gets thrown in it might be
>      cold, it might not come into contact
>      with the meat, and so on.
> 2. According to many sources, the prohibition of cooking meat and milk
>      together is due to the concern that
>      one might come to eat the mixture (see
>      Kesef Mishnah Tumas Mes 1:4).
>      Accordingly, where there is no chance
>      of this happening, some authorities
>      are lenient (Dovev Meisharim, Har
>      Tzvi).
> 3. Even if a davar gush cooks, it might not be called “derech bishul” to
>      prohibit the cooking of meat and milk
>      together (see Pri Megadim, Intro.,
>      s.v. Od Adaber).
> 4. Because both foods are (usually) already cooked, some authorities
>      maintain there is no longer a
>      prohibition of cooking meat and milk
>      (see Chasam Sofer YD 82; Pri Toar
>      87:3; Aruch Hashulchan 87:13; Machazik
>      Berachah 87:12).
>
> The combination of the factors above
>   would seem sufficient to permit the
>   use of a single garbage bin for meat
>   and milk.

Comment: The drain is even better than the garbage bin, as there's likely to be a chunk of hot solid meat/cheese anywhere.

Comment: I think you mean "unlikely to..."?

Answer (score 0):

Lchatchila it is not recommended even directly down the drain. If it happenned and there were dishes that got splattered it would not make your dishes Treif as the milk is cold.

Comment: @gers i meant directly into the drain

Comment: Not recommended, as someone might forget and pour hot water in the sink a minute later, cooking some of the remaining milk into the sink. But if milk was poured down the drain, just make sure everything's throughly washed down (with soap and **cold** water), and you're fine.

Comment: @R'avrohom, please clarify that in the question, then.

Comment: @R'Shalom, why soap? Cold milk will run down the drain with just water. In any event, do you have a source, please? 

@R'Gershon Gold, do you have a source, please?